# Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using JPA Repository[**Using Spring Data**] to query my database in order to return me a list of events that occurred between the dates I submited. I have class with the following variables that will serve as a request body(**@RequestBody**) in the controller:

//**NOTE ->  My Date must be a String**

```
private String initialDate;
private String finalDate;
```

I pass the following values int POSTMAN

```
{
    "initialDate":"2018-09-29",
    "finalDate":"2018-09-30"

}
```

This is my correspondent Model class

```
private String initialDate;
private String finalDate;
private String moreInfo;
private String SomeMoreInfo;
```

I would like the API to return me the info between those dates, for that I use the following query in my repository layer.

```
@Query("SELECT u from Kitchen u WHERE STR_TO_DATE(u.date, '%a, %c %b %Y %k:%i:%s') between :initial_day AND :final_day")            
    List<Cozinha> findPlateByDate(@Param("initial_day") String initial_day,@Param("final_day") String final_day);
```

The following error appears in POSTMAN [as posted in the title of the question]

```
 "message": "Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist",
```

The following error appears in netbeans server console

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

My question is, I am doing the query right? Our the syntax wrong?

Comment: FYI JPQL has no such function `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: I have a hunch that this might be a bug in Spring Data JPA. Could you post the full stack trace and also which version of Spring Data JPA you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This broken cause handling of colons in string literal is broken.

A workaround would be to get rid of colons in queries as they are getting interpreted as bind parameters.